# Dependency Injection in multiple Activities with Dagger and Room

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-room, dagger

I am fairly new to Android coming from a c# background and was came across dependency injection with dagger. I managed to create a simple example but was wondering how i can use my repository (i tried to use the repository pattern here) in another activity. So my structure is following:
[image: Project structure]
When i try to create a workout in my MainActivity class it works just fine. So i added following line to my AddWorkoutActivity class

```
@Inject
public WorkoutRepository workoutRepository;
```

But when i try to save the workout I always get a null reference error on the workoutRepository so i do miss something in my understanding how the DI works here. Maybe someone can give me a hint what i have to do so my repository is instantiated the correct way in my Activity.

// Edit:
I think the problem is that i call the DaggerAppComponent.builder()... in the onCreate Method in my MainActivity class, so the AddWorkoutActivity won`t know anything of that. But where do i initialize the DaggerAppComponent so that both activities can acces it correctly?

Best regards

**App Component:**

```
package jh.projects.wodm8.di;

import android.app.Application;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import dagger.Component;
import jh.projects.wodm8.view.MainActivity;
import jh.projects.wodm8.data.WorkoutDao;
import jh.projects.wodm8.repository.DemoDatabase;
import jh.projects.wodm8.repository.WorkoutRepository;

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, RoomModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

WorkoutDao workoutDao();

DemoDatabase demoDatabase();

WorkoutRepository productRepository();

Application application();
}
```

**AppModule**

```
package jh.projects.wodm8.di;

import android.app.Application;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;

@Module
public class AppModule {

    Application mApplication;

    public AppModule(Application application) {
        mApplication = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Application providesApplication() {
        return mApplication;
    }
}
```

**RoomModule**

```
package jh.projects.wodm8.di;

import android.app.Application;

import androidx.room.Room;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;
import jh.projects.wodm8.data.WorkoutDao;
import jh.projects.wodm8.repository.DemoDatabase;
import jh.projects.wodm8.repository.WorkoutDataSource;
import jh.projects.wodm8.repository.WorkoutRepository;

@Module
public class RoomModule{

    private DemoDatabase demoDatabase;

    public RoomModule(Application mApplication) {
        demoDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(mApplication, DemoDatabase.class, "demo-db").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    DemoDatabase providesRoomDatabase() {
        return demoDatabase;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    WorkoutDao providesWorkoutDao(DemoDatabase demoDatabase) {
        return demoDatabase.getWorkoutDao();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    WorkoutRepository providesWorkoutRepository(WorkoutDao workoutDao) {
        return new WorkoutDataSource(workoutDao);
    }
}
```

**WorkoutDataSource**

```
package jh.projects.wodm8.repository;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;

import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import jh.projects.wodm8.data.Workout;
import jh.projects.wodm8.data.WorkoutDao;

public class WorkoutDataSource implements WorkoutRepository {

    private WorkoutDao workoutDao;

    @Inject
    public WorkoutDataSource(WorkoutDao workoutDao) {
        this.workoutDao = workoutDao;
    }

    @Override
    public LiveData<Workout> findById(int id) {
        return workoutDao.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public LiveData<List<Workout>> findAll() {
        return workoutDao.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(Workout workout) {
        workoutDao.insert(workout);
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Workout workout) {
        return workoutDao.delete(workout);
    }
}
```

**WorkoutRepository**

```
package jh.projects.wodm8.repository;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;

import java.util.List;

import jh.projects.wodm8.data.Workout;

public interface WorkoutRepository {
    LiveData<Workout> findById(int id);

    LiveData<List<Workout>> findAll();

    void insert(Workout workout);

    int delete(Workout workout);

}
```

**MainActivity**
    package jh.projects.wodm8.view;

```
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import jh.projects.wodm8.R;
import jh.projects.wodm8.data.Workout;
import jh.projects.wodm8.di.AppModule;
import jh.projects.wodm8.di.DaggerAppComponent;
import jh.projects.wodm8.di.RoomModule;
import jh.projects.wodm8.repository.WorkoutRepository;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    public WorkoutRepository workoutRepository;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AddWorkoutActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(getApplication()))
                .roomModule(new RoomModule(getApplication()))
                .build()
                .inject(this);

        workoutRepository.findAll().observe(this, new Observer<List<Workout>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Workout> products) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.format("Product size: %s", products.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**AddWorkoutActivity**

```
package jh.projects.wodm8.view;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import jh.projects.wodm8.R;
import jh.projects.wodm8.data.Workout;
import jh.projects.wodm8.di.AppModule;
import jh.projects.wodm8.di.DaggerAppComponent;
import jh.projects.wodm8.di.RoomModule;
import jh.projects.wodm8.repository.DemoDatabase;
import jh.projects.wodm8.repository.WorkoutRepository;

import android.app.Application;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class AddWorkoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    public WorkoutRepository workoutRepository;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_workout);

        final Button button = findViewById(R.id.saveWorkout);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Workout workout = new Workout();
                EditText txtTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.workoutTitleText);
                workout.setTitle(txtTitle.getText().toString());

                try {
                    workoutRepository.insert(workout);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.v("AddWorkout", e.getMessage());
                }

                Toast.makeText(AddWorkoutActivity.this, "Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

// EDIT: 
Thanks to a_local_nobody for the links to start with Dagger:
https://youtu.be/Qwk7ESmaCq0

I found another source to start with dagger that helped me too:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/262-dependency-injection-in-android-with-dagger-2-and-kotlin#toc-anchor-005

Comment: i realize this doesn't answer your question, but have a look at this set of tutorials, it might be really useful for you to learn dagger for android, you'll get the basics of it after the first 3 or 4, i hope this somewhat helps you https://youtu.be/Qwk7ESmaCq0

Comment: just a side note, this is where i learned dagger from and it really gives you some good overview of how it works, consider giving my comment an upvote if you DO end up finding the tutorials useful :) all the best

Comment: Thanks for the comment, maybe i should make a step back and learn more of the basics. I will definitly try this out and watch the vids. Thank you

Comment: ok, i submitted somewhat of an answer, hopefully this has at least helped you somewhat, take some time to go through those tutorials and the repo i sent you, give my answer an upvote if it at least somewhat helped or mark as answer if you find what you're looking for, all the best, happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to give you a bit of a more complete answer, taken from this online resource https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-dagger2-example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mindorks/example/android_dagger2_example/DemoApplication.java

(i'm just going over it briefly to give you a better understanding)

Create an application class which extends Application and implement this :

```
     @Override
     public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent
                                    .builder()
                                    .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
                                    .build();
        applicationComponent.inject(this);
}
```

you have to define your own applicationComponent though, just going through this briefly.
after that, you should be able to use your repositories in several different places with the annotation of `@Inject` where you need them, just remember to actually call the injection where you need it, making use of

`getActivityComponent().inject(this);` or `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` where you need to, hopefully this github example and the tutorials are enough to answer some of your questions

Comment: Tahnk you. That helped me understand it more clear. It didn´t solve my problem yet but as i mentioned before i think i have to start with a more simple example ;-)

Comment: no problem @jhen, dagger is pretty complicated for everyone starting out (it feels overwhelming with a lot of stuff going on) but once you have a working example you'll always be able to use it, so i'd definitely recommend starting from scratch somewhere, all the best and happy coding :)